# AsyncAppender does not wait for buffer to be full before writing

Tags: java, logging, log4j, asyncappender

I am learning about Log4j currently and the book I am using is explaining AsyncAppenders. I set a buffer size to be 128 (LoggingEvents). The book explains that no messages will be printed until the buffer size is reached, however my program prints the logging messages regardless of the buffer size.

Why is this the case? I would appreciate any other pointers about AsyncAppenders if anyone has knowledge about using them :)

Log4j.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

    <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
    debug="true">

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <param name="BufferSize" value="128"/>
    </appender>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%t] - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.example.christopher" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
    <priority value="debug"/>
    </root>
    </log4j:configuration>
```

Java code

```
package org.example.christopher;

import org.apache.log4j.*;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;


public class AsyncLogging{

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AsyncLogging.class.getPackage().getName());
private AsyncAppender asyncAppender = null;
private ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = null;

public AsyncLogging(){

try{
logger.setAdditivity(false);
asyncAppender = (AsyncAppender) logger.getAppender("ASYNC");
asyncAppender.setBufferSize(128);
}
catch (Exception e){
System.out.println("error: " + e.toString());
}

}

public void doLogging(){
logger.debug("Debug 1");
logger.debug("Debug 2");
logger.debug("Debug 3");
//logger.debug("Debug 4");
//logger.debug("Debug 5");
}


public static void main(String ... args){
AsyncLogging asyncLogging = new AsyncLogging();
asyncLogging.doLogging();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the [javadocs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AsyncAppender.html) or the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/org/apache/log4j/AsyncAppender.java) of `AsyncAppender` say that no messages will be printed until the buffer is full.  Indeed, according to my reading of the code:

1. The `AsyncAppender.Dispatcher` thread that does the writing will be woken whenever an event is appended and the buffer is empty.
2. Once woken, it won't go to sleep until the buffer is empty.

That is pretty much the opposite of what the book you are reading says.  (Assuming that you have read it correctly.)

Comment: "This example simply sets the buffer size to 4 for the AsyncAppender
being used. The AsyncAppender will not print any message so long as the number of logging
events is less than the buffer size. Once the number of logging events exceeds the buffer size,
the buffer is flushed and all the messages will be printed." Pro Apache Log4J second edition

Comment: In that case, the book is plainly incorrect.  If it had said *"... it is not specified ..."* that would have been correct.  But the source code plainly contradicts the book, and the source code is definitive.

Comment: The only possible explanation that might make the book sort of correct would be that early versions of `AsyncAppender` might have worked like that.  However, the intended behavior in the code has been "eager" async flushing since v1.2.8 ... which is the earliest version for which source code is easily accessible.  (It is all in the Grepcode link above.)